# Looping through csv files and creating a DataFrame that summarize info by locating text in columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, for-loop, append

The script that I have so far (see below) does that:
1: looping through a folder and convert .xlsx in .csv.
2: looping through the csv list and populate a dataframe with data extracted from each one of them.
3: append a new column that is populated with the filename.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
cwd = os.path.abspath('') 
files = os.listdir(cwd)  

df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        df1 = pd.read_csv(file, header = None,encoding='latin1')
        df1 = df1.assign(Filename= os.path.basename(file))
        df = df1.append(df,ignore_index=False)
```

What I want to do now is while still in the 'file' loop;

The 1st column (will be named Pozo): where dataframe column number 1 contains 'Pozo:', extract the value from the same row but column 3.

To populate the second column a search for text 'MD' has to be done inside the first column (column 0) of the dataframe and has to be populated with all the values below the row where text is found inside this same column.

The outcome looks like the joined picture now. The image show what I want to extract from it (in red in the searched text, and in yellow the values to extract)

What I want is to take the dataframe shown in the image and 'clean it' like so:

|  | Pozo | MD | Filename |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | NWI-RC-176 calidad | 0.00 | NWIRC-176-22_SPT_Offline_OutRun_QC.csv |
| Second | NWI-RC-176 calidad | 5.00 | NWIRC-176-22_SPT_Offline_OutRun_QC.csv |
| [...] |  |  |  |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgAt9.png)
Thanks for helping me !!

Comment: can you show how the output should look like?

Comment: I updated the question with the wanted output

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps

Choose the value from column 3, where column 1 has 'POZO', and assign to variable

```
var_pozo = df.at[df[df['1'] == 'Pozo:'].index[0],'3']  
var_pozo
```

to choose all values below where MD Is found, we first find that row
then choose all rows from below that index and assign to another DF (md_df)
then find a first null value and exclude that from the md_df

```
# all rows from DF where MD is found are selected and assigned to md_df

md_df = df[df[df['0'] == 'MD'].index[0]:].reset_index() 

# find the first null value and select all rows above the null
md_df = md_df[:md_df[md_df['0'].isnull()].index[0]]['0'].reset_index()
md_df
```

We add the required columns in md_df

```
md_df['Pozo']     = var_pozo
md_df['filename'] = 'your filename' # replace this with your file variable
md_df.drop(columns='index', inplace=True)
md_df.rename(columns={'0': 'MD'}, inplace=True)
md_df
```

md_df becomes your extracted df
here is the output with the test csv I created

```
    MD  Pozo    filename
0   (m) NWI-RC-176 calidad  your filename
1   0   NWI-RC-176 calidad  your filename
2   5   NWI-RC-176 calidad  your filename
3   10  NWI-RC-176 calidad  your filename
4   15  NWI-RC-176 calidad  your filename
```